# byte order conversion for signed integer

Tags: c, endianness

I have a problem translate byte order between host(CPU dependent) and network(big endian). These are all the APIs(in "arpa/inet.h" for Linux) I've found that might solve my problem.

```
 uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);

 uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);

 uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);

 uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

Except for one thing, **they only handle unsigned integer**(2 bytes or 4 byte).

So is there any approach to handle **signed integer case**? In other words, how to implement the following functions(APIs)?

```
 int32_t htonl(int32_t hostlong);

 int16_t htons(int16_t hostshort);

 int32_t ntohl(int32_t netlong);

 int16_t ntohs(int16_t netshort);
```

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878781/signed-integer-network-and-host-conversion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically speaking, it doesn't matter what the value is inside the variable since you just want to borrow the functionality. When assigning a signed to an unsigned, its value changes but the bits are the same. So converting it back to signed is alright.

Edit: As amrit said, it is a duplicate of [Signed Integer Network and Host Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878781/signed-integer-network-and-host-conversion).

Comment: Thanks. You answer provide more help than that of the the duplicate.